# Docusign Connect API : Not receiving request parameters in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rack, docusignapi

I have a docusign account, where I am creating an envelope of multiple/single documents and trying to send them through "Connect" to a particular endpoint/url after signing of the documents is done.

Now I have two applications for the endpoint url. 
The first application is a Rails 2.3.1 app in which I get all the params including byte streams of the files sent through docusign.
This works fine.

The second application is a Rails 4.2.2 with ruby 2.2.2 . Now in this application, when I receive the request from the docusign, the request does not contain any params.

Can any one tell why there is difference in the behavior between Rails 2.3.1 and Rails 4.2.2.

Please Note in both the cases , the request is a POST request.

**Update**:

We have deployed a sample Rails 4 app on Heroku. Below is the link:
https://aqueous-harbor-4271.herokuapp.com/docusign/consume
which can be used to test a POST request that docusign sends through connect api. Just set up the connection endpoint as the above URL.
It just renders the incoming request parameters in json as response.

Comment: So the issue is that the in-coming Connect msg to you app is handled differently your 2 different apps? I would first use the Connect management panel to send and re-send the same connect message to both of your apps.  That way you'll. Confirm that your 2nd app is the issue.  Then debug by tracing the handling of the incoming msg throughout rails stack. Since the incoming msg  is not a standard request from a human's browser, rails could be "helpfully" stripping something off the incoming. I'd also ask in the rails tag. Show the raw connect msg vs what arrives at your app's controller

Comment: With the rails 4.2.2 application , I dont get anything in the params . Ideally I should have got the files and other params that docusign usually posts .

Comment: We debugged in the same way as u have suggested.
But we could not pin point any thing in error logs.
Can u please suggest some other ways to debug from docusign perspective. @LarryK

Comment: Login to your developer sandbox account, go to your Preferences and enable **Request Logging**.  Then make some API calls, go back to that screen, and you'll be able to download the request logs that were generated.  Those will show the raw request you made and response that came back in...

Comment: Hi All. The issue has been fixed. It was related to Rails 4 stack where in it truncates the request parameters if the request method is POST and content type is application/xml. No issue with docusign.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407625/post-request-parameters-getting-truncated-in-rails-4-2-2-with-content-type-as-a/33407983#33407983

Answer (score 2):

Vipul said, "The issue has been fixed. It was related to Rails 4 stack where in it truncates the request parameters if the request method is POST and content type is application/xml. No issue with docusign."

I'm putting the answer here so this doesn't show up as an unanswered question when searching Stack Overflow.