# Post request parameters getting truncated in Rails 4.2.2 with content type as "Application/xml"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rack, rails-4-2-1

I have this below observation:

I deployed a sample Rails 4.2.2 application with a controller and action to receive a POST request.

Now If I send a POST request to this application with some POST body say a hash like `{"1"=>"hello","2"=>"bye"}` and if the content type of the request is `"application/xml"`, I don't receive any parameters in my Rails app.

If I change content type of the same request to some thing else , I will get the parameters properly.

Can some one please tell my why this behaviour is there in ***Rails 4.2.2*** with a ***POST*** request having content type as `"application/xml"`.

Comment: can you post you consol results?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic parsing of XML bodies was removed in rails 4.0 and extracted into a [gem](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-xml_parser)

Even with that gem your request body isn't valid XML.

Comment: Thanks a lot Frederick...Using this Gem helped me to get the params....
But I wonder why did the rails team decided not to support parsing of xml bodies in Rails 4.0....???